# Generate Outlook mention @ in Python

Tags: python, outlook, mention

I am trying to automatize an email sender in which I would like to mention people (@) using this new feature of Outlook.

I have tried to get the HTML source code of a mention which looks like :

```
"<p class=MsoNormal><a id=SOME_ID"
    "href=""mailto:john.doe@smith.com"">@DOE John</p>"
```

but even when populating `"id="` with an id taken from an email sample, the sent email does not trigger the @ function in outlook (ie just display the name with a mailto hyperlink)

Is there a workaround to this ? Maybe in module win32com.client, there is a .mention attribute to CreateItem ?

full code :

```
import win32com.client as win32

def Emailer(text, subject, recipient):

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(True)

Emailer("<p class=MsoNormal><a id=OWAAM2940D6AF10AB4D2E93456BEC399E6B4F "
        "href=""mailto:john.doe@smith.com""> &#64; DOE John</p>"
        , "test", "john.doe@smith.com")
```

Comment: did you tried the html code **`&#64;`**

Comment: yes, same result unfortunately

Comment: anyone on this ?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: edited in the first post